# CSS Based on parent div

Tags: html, css

Not sure my title relays my overall question, but here goes.

I have HTML similar to this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Some of the CSS:

```css
#menu {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#menu > li > a {
    color: #fff;
}
#menu > li:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

On my home page, I have the links set to Color: White;
I would like to add class="productmenu" to the parent div only on a few product pages and have my css change the menu font color to black.

```
<div id="nav" class="productmenu">
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add one more CSS rule:

```css
.productmenu #menu > li > a {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Ok, you are awesome!  I've been trying different combos of classes and Id's but for some reason, never tried that one.  Thanks DFSQ!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply combine the id selector `#` and the class selector `.` like this:

```css
#nav.productmenu #menu > li > a {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Timo!  I appreciate the answer as well.